# Azure data factory Pipeline is failing : spark.rpc.message.maxSize

Tags: azure, google-cloud-dataflow, azure-data-factory

"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 10:0 was 135562862 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values."

I have simple adf pipeline which was working fine but started failing from few days.

The source is a REST API call.
Can you please help in fixing this?, where can I change the suggested setting.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 10:0 was 135562862 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.

According to the error instruction, the problem appears to be caused by overloaded spark resources. Please experiment with an Integration runtime and increase the **compute size** of the **Data Flow Integration**. compute size is size of compute used in spark cluster.

- Go to linked service and click on pencil icon beside integration runtime.
  [image]
- Data Flow Runtime >> Compute size
  [image]

Comment: Thanks, Pratik, I tried the above suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: Please raise a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket) for deeper investigation as you are still facing same issue or check if your rest Api is giving data in proper format.